# Image saving issue in marshmallow devices

Tags: android, android-camera, android-6.0-marshmallow

Aim :my application take images from camera and gallery.And crop this image and save to external storage.

Issue :  Application shows unfortunately photos has stooped message while clicking save button from crop page.The error happens only in marshmallow  devices.working fine in all other  devices.

my code to take image is given below:

```
final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CategoryActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Select Pic Using...");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {

                        try {
                            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                            pic = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                    "tmp_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");

                            picUri = Uri.fromFile(pic);

                            cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);

                            cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, LOAD_IMAGE_CAMERA);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);


                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), LOAD_IMAGE_GALLARY);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("profile", false);
                        editor.commit();
                        //  finish();
                    }
                }
            });

            builder.show();
        }
    });

if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("profile", false);
        editor.commit();

        Intent in = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, ImageCrop.class);

        in.putExtra("URI", picUri);
        in.putExtra("cat", type);
        in.putExtra("contest_idadd", contestid_i);


        startActivity(in);


    } else if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_GALLARY) {
        if (data != null) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("profile", false);
            editor.commit();

            picUri = data.getData();

            Intent in = new Intent(CategoryActivity.this, ImageCrop.class);
            in.putExtra("URI", picUri);
            in.putExtra("cat", type);
            in.putExtra("contest_idadd", contestid_i);

            startActivity(in);

        }
    }
```

And crop using the below code

```
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

            if (bundle != null) {
                picUri = (Uri) bundle.get("URI");
                cat_value = (String) bundle.get("cat");
            }
    protected void CropImage() {
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                intent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    Log.d("piccccc",picUri+"");
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 3);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
                intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);
                intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_IMAGE);

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE) {
                if (data != null) {
                    // get the returned data

                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                    // get the cropped bitmap
                    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

                    image_array.add(photo);

                    crop.setImageBitmap(photo);

                    if (pic != null) {

                        if (pic.delete()) {

                        }
            }
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("cropppppppppppppp", requestCode + "");
                }
            }
```

In marshmallow devices images not found in saved external storage path.Anyone please give me a solution.

Comment: You should start by learning what is the error your application is throwing instead of just asking for the exact answer is stackoverflow.

Comment: There is no error in application.No error shows in Logcat.

Comment: "Application shows unfortunately photos has stooped message" if that shows it should show in Logcat. Start by making sure you're NOT filtering the logs at all, then look for the crash stacktrace.

Comment: this message shows in crop page not in my application.

Comment: Even then, it should give an error from that respective application. First you need to identify that its not your application crashing because its passing bad arguments to a client. Or the app you're passing your data to isn't handling it cleanly. Or its as simple as the intent your building cannot be resolved.

Comment: Issue only in marshmallow devices, it works fine in all other devices.

Comment: Is there anything that would help with being able to trace what is wrong? There has to ideally be something in the logs. If not, then you're going to have to do trial and error. Without more information its not possible to help you. Logs are important for solving an issue like this.

Comment: images not found in saved externa storage path.

Comment: Also with Marshemellow permission structure has changed. They are at the discretion of the user. Is it possible that you're being denied permission?

Comment: Post the error into your post, don't post it into the comments. Post the full error as as it appears in the Logs.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns null in marshmallow devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add proper implementation of taking 
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
permission in your code.
You need to handle permissions in your code from marshmallow and above:

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Added permissions at runtime.But Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns null in marshmallow devices

Comment: @krishna : How did you fix that. Am also facing same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Or build your app with SDK 22 or below, TargetSdkVersion = 22